# Ruby on rails AngularJS - create multiple models from direct upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby

I recently am given a task by upper management to implement a mass upload coupon task. The goal is to allow users to upload an list of coupon codes (excel or csv), and subsequently giving these coupons codes attributes such as start date, expiry, quantity and so on.

I have already implemented a form to input these attributes. The current implementation method I am doing is as follows:

1.I upload a list of coupon codes (eg: 333245454dfee) and I do not write them directly to the database, instead I converted them to string and display on a page for the user to view. (done)

2.from that view page, there is a form with all the attributes. The user can then input these attributes. (done)

3.The user can create all of these coupons codes with the attributes set.

However, I am stuck now because I am unsure of how to mass create multiple codes and attach all the attributes to them. Right now, I can only create one coupon at a time.

So, to summarize, I would like to ask is it possible to

1. have a field that contains all the codes I have uploaded
2. I have others fields for different attributes
3. how to create all the codes I have uploaded as separate models.

I do not need the codes, I would like to hear what approach there are. I am thinking of creating a variable to store these coupons codes first, then loop them. But I have no idea how to do all of that by pressing one single button.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, how I would approach this problem would be to have the user upload an csv file with 1 column and multiple rows of coupon. Using carrierwave to upload the file and parse the csv file. After parsing it, you should have an array of coupon and you can just input them into the database.

A good reference for your problem would be [http://railscasts.com/episodes/396-importing-csv-and-excel](http://railscasts.com/episodes/396-importing-csv-and-excel?view=comments)

Comment: I managed to do it. I just upload the csv file and store the rows as an array. Then I pass that variable to angularcontroller. When I submit the form, I just loop the variable with the coupon code, and do multiple transaction. The key is to edit the coupon model to allow rails to create multiple times.